# Two level directory listing with Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory-listing

I've been trying to get a very specific directory listing with no success so far.

Lets say I have a folder structure like this:

- C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1
- C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Web\
- C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Web\ (site code, the structure goes on)
- C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Scripts\ (db scripts)
- C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder2
- C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder2\Web\ (site code, the structure goes on)

Now, when I use foreach, it will look like this:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem $UpdateDir -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1 | Select-Object FullName

ForEach($folder in $folders) {
   $folder = folder.TrimStart("@{FullName=").TrimEnd("}") #To get a clean name
}
```

The result will be as follows:

```
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder2
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Web\
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Web\ (site code, the structure goes on)
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Scripts\ (db scripts)
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder2\Web\ (site code, the structure goes on)
```

Which is not ok.
It should look like this:

```
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Web\
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Web\ (site code, the structure goes on)
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder1\Scripts\ (db scripts)
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder2
C:\inetpub\updates\updatefolder2\Web\ (site code, the structure goes on)
```

Any fresh ideas ? I've tried several things, other than that foreach loop, still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. The code you have posted here seems to have many typos. 
2. What are you trying to achieve?
3. Both of the results you have posted in question seems same except the sequence/order. Can you please check once and confirm?

Comment: The problem is the horrible hack you're using to get the full name. Remove the entire `ForEach` loop and change the first line to `$folders = Get-ChildItem $UpdateDir -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1 | Select-Object -Expand FullName`

Comment: @SavindraSingh Typos ? Where ? Other than the fact that I forgot to add the variable to actually output.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks man, and sorry for the horrible hack :D This looks alot better.

Comment: `$folder = folder.TrimStart("@{FullName=").TrimEnd("}")` Here, you forgot to add $ in folder.TrimStart()

Comment: @SavindraSingh Yes, you are right. I wrote it over instead of copying. The script didn't have that bug. I have now done away the trimming though, thanks to people here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ForEach loop is not needed it can be replaced by `-expandproperty` in the select object.  If I understood the question correctly, the issue that you bring up is that the results aren't sorted.  The answer is to sort the results using `Sort-Object'

## Example

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem $UpdateDir -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1 | 
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullname | 
     Sort-Object
$folders
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I wanted out of this. And sorry for the poor explanation, I suck at explaining stuff, I would be the crappiest teacher. This is also why I added the visual representation.
I tried to crack it for a week and the solution was so simple, damn.